# How to get the color of button not to change onclick

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys this might be a simple questions but cant seem to figure it out in bootstrap i have a simple button :

```
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Kontakta oss</button>
```

I have edited in CSS etc but when its clicked it has a huge blue border around it and the color goes to orange when clicked.

I would like it so that the color stays the same which is black right now and that the border does not change color at all , i just am not sure what the class names are for this

So its not the `:Hover` class  its the `click class` but again no idea whats it called or the `visit` something

Thanks

EDIT:

[image]

You can see the first button is what it looks like, but when it is clicked on , for a few seconds it changes to orange and then back to black , i want to have it not changed color when the user clicks on it

Comment: set the outline rule: `button:focus {outline: none;}` But if you do this then you remove the ability for users to know what button has focus.

Comment: @Intervalia buts its the class im looking for once clicked its like visit or clicked , no idea whats its called

Comment: `:visited` is for the `<a>` tag and not for buttons. Once you click on it, try to tab away. Does the bg-color and border-color revert back?

Comment: @Intervalia Thats not it im afraid

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Without being certain (no css provided) it might be a `:focus` you are looking for

Comment: You can see the entire list of pseudo classes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes. I think the pseudo class you are looking for is either `:active` or `:focus`

Comment: @RonTheOld Which version of bootstrap?

Comment: This is the code : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39541/ version 3

Comment: Its just when its clicked the background of the button goes to orange for some silly reason

Comment: Updated my questions with a picture for better understanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Bootstrap-specific issue, as you are using a Bootstrap class that stylizes buttons. To override it use this:

```css
.btn-warning.active, .btn-warning:active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-warning {
    /* STYLES GO HERE */
    color:white!important;
    background-color:black!important;
    border-color:white!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Kontakta oss</button>
```

**NOTE:** In my example code I am using `!important` to override the default Bootstrap styling because of the way SO loads snippet CSS. This is bad practice and not necessary as long as you load these overrides *after* the Bootstrap CSS has been loaded.

Comment: Updated my questions with a picture for better understanding

Comment: I understand the question, you are using Bootstrap classes that have predefined styles for buttons. In order to change the styles, you will have to override the default Bootstrap styling as I outlined above.

Comment: Thats perfect thanks , just couldn't remember what the name of the class was :)